# Transparent selectable png

Tags: javascript, css, png

I have a transparent png of a star and I want users to be able to click on the star and JUST the star, not the negative spaces. Is this a way I'd like to NOT do that in canvas. Is there any way to do this with CSS/Javascript?

Thanks,
dp

Comment: You could use a map, as described in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: You can use `clip-path` - the generator here even has a star shape: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/